# Do I need normalize.css when developing my own Wordpress-theme?

Tags: theme-development, css

I'm developing my own Wordpress theme and I'm trying to make it as light as possible.
I started from the Underscores starter theme, but they use normalize.css to reset the styles.

Is it necessary to include it in my theme or is there a better method?

Comment: It's a helpful thing to do for consistency of looks across browsers. not totally necessary, but could reduce the need for browser-specific design fixes later. I reckon it's a good thing, so have included it in my theme.

Comment: It's not 'necessary', but it'll help you get consistent styles across browsers. The CSS in your theme can be literally anything you want, but there's a reason people use normalize. It helps.

Comment: I guess I'll keep it in there, just to be sure everything will look okay. I just wanted to reduce the amount of code in my theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web standards are pretty good these days and IMO I don't think things like normalize are nearly as necessary as years ago.

I would recommend having a [look through the CSS](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) file and deciding for yourself.

You can always just grab what styles you think are relevant and include them in your own CSS. This will cut down on a dependency and make you more aware of what code you are including in your own theme.

Quick note:  You can use [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) to look up specific styles or tags you might have questions about.

For Example, normalize includes this CSS...

```
main {
   display: block;
}
```

If you look up main [HERE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-html_elements_main), you will see it was added to the spec late and could cause bugs in IE if you don't apply `block` to it.